# Using Shaders LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, glsl, shader

I'm in major need for help. I am working on a 2d game in libgdx. All is working well, and today I decided to make a small 2d particle system to make fireworks. I remembered I had recently accomplished this task using shaders in 3d in the book *OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android: A Quick Start Guide*. So I copied most of the code and started modifying some things so it would work with Libgdx and in 2d. How this particle editor works is there is one big float array that holds 8 things per particle: 2 positions, x and y; 3 colors, rgb; 2 directions, x and y; 1 start time. Now this repeats for every particle allowed in the array. I set the max particles to 10,000, so 80,000 floats in this array, meaning 320,000 bytes. Anyways, now I have all of these attributes. Now I put these attributes into the shader program. The shader program uses these to move the particles by the direction, fade the color by time, and apply gravity. So anyways, it worked uses pure OpenGL, but I wanted to use the LibGDX framework. I tried to keep as much as the old code as I could. I thought what I did would work, but it won't show anything. Here is the code...

ParticleFirework.java:

```
public class ParticleFirework {

    private final Vector2 position;
    private final Vector2 direction;
    private final int color;

    private final float angleVariance;
    private final float speedVariance;

    private final Random random = new Random();
    private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] directionVector = new float[4];
    private float[] resultVector = new float[4];

    public ParticleFirework(Vector2 position, Vector2 direction, int color,
            float angleVarianceInDegrees, float speedVariance) {
        this.position = position;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.color = color;
        this.angleVariance = angleVarianceInDegrees;
        this.speedVariance = speedVariance;

        directionVector[0] = direction.x;
        directionVector[1] = direction.y;
        directionVector[2] = 0;
    }

    public void addParticles(ParticleSystem particleSystem, float currentTime,
            int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            setRotateEulerM(rotationMatrix, 0, (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f)
                    * angleVariance, (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f)
                    * angleVariance, (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f)
                    * angleVariance);

            multiplyMV(resultVector, 0, rotationMatrix, 0, directionVector, 0);

            float speedAdjustment = 1f + random.nextFloat() * speedVariance;

            Vector2 thisDirection = new Vector2(resultVector[0]
                    * speedAdjustment, resultVector[1] * speedAdjustment);

            particleSystem.addParticle(position, color, thisDirection,
                    currentTime);
        }
    }

}
```

ParticleSystem.java:

```
public class ParticleSystem {
    private static final int PARTICLE_POSITION_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int PARTICLE_COLOR_COUNT = 3;
    private static final int PARTICLE_DIRECTION_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int PARTICLE_START_TIME_COUNT = 1;
    private static final int BYTES_IN_A_FLOAT = 4;

    private static final int TOTAL_COUNT = PARTICLE_POSITION_COUNT
            + PARTICLE_COLOR_COUNT + PARTICLE_DIRECTION_COUNT
            + PARTICLE_START_TIME_COUNT;

    private static final int STRIDE = TOTAL_COUNT * BYTES_IN_A_FLOAT;

    private final float[] particles;
    private final int maxParticleCount;

    private int currentParticleCount;
    private int nextParticle;
    private FloatBuffer particleFloatBuffer;

    public ParticleSystem(int maxParticleCount) {
        particles = new float[maxParticleCount * TOTAL_COUNT];
        this.maxParticleCount = maxParticleCount;
        particleFloatBuffer = ByteBuffer
                .allocateDirect(particles.length * BYTES_IN_A_FLOAT)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(particles);
    }

    public void addParticle(Vector2 position, int color, Vector2 direction,
            float particleStartTime) {
        final int particleOffset = nextParticle * TOTAL_COUNT;

        int currentOffset = particleOffset;
        nextParticle++;

        if (currentParticleCount < maxParticleCount) {
            currentParticleCount++;
        }

        if (nextParticle == maxParticleCount) {
            nextParticle = 0;
        }

        particles[currentOffset++] = position.x;
        particles[currentOffset++] = position.y;

        particles[currentOffset++] = Color.red(color) / 255f;
        particles[currentOffset++] = Color.green(color) / 255f;
        particles[currentOffset++] = Color.blue(color) / 255f;

        particles[currentOffset++] = direction.x;
        particles[currentOffset++] = direction.y;

        particles[currentOffset++] = particleStartTime;

        particleFloatBuffer.position(particleOffset);
        particleFloatBuffer.put(particles, particleOffset, TOTAL_COUNT);
        particleFloatBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void bindData(ShaderProgram particleProgram) {
        int dataOffset = 0;
        particleProgram.setVertexAttribute("a_Position",
                PARTICLE_POSITION_COUNT, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE,
                dataOffset);
        dataOffset += PARTICLE_POSITION_COUNT;

        particleProgram.setVertexAttribute("a_Color",
                PARTICLE_COLOR_COUNT, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE,
                dataOffset);
        dataOffset += PARTICLE_COLOR_COUNT;

        particleProgram.setVertexAttribute("a_DirectionVector",
                PARTICLE_DIRECTION_COUNT, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE,
                dataOffset);
        dataOffset += PARTICLE_DIRECTION_COUNT;

        particleProgram.setVertexAttribute("a_ParticleStartTime",
                PARTICLE_START_TIME_COUNT, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE,
                dataOffset);
    }

    public void draw() {
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, currentParticleCount);
    }
}
```

ParticleGame.java:

```
public class ParticlesGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    ShaderProgram particleProgram;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    Texture img;

    private ParticleSystem particleSystem;
    private ParticleFirework firework;

    private long globalStartTime;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        globalStartTime = System.nanoTime();

        final Vector2 particleDirection = new Vector2(0f, 0.5f);
        final float angleVarianceInDegrees = 5f;
        final float speedVariance = 1f;

        particleProgram = new ShaderProgram("shaders/particle_shader.vs",
                "shaders/particle_shader.fs");

        particleSystem = new ParticleSystem(10000);

        firework = new ParticleFirework(new Vector2(0f, 0f), particleDirection,
                Color.rgb(255, 50, 5), angleVarianceInDegrees, speedVariance);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        float currentTime = (System.nanoTime() - globalStartTime) / 1000000000f;

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        firework.addParticles(particleSystem, currentTime, 5);

        particleProgram.begin();
        FloatBuffer matrixBuffer = ByteBuffer
                .allocateDirect(camera.combined.getValues().length * 4)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer()
                .put(camera.combined.getValues());

        /** Set the uniforms **/
        particleProgram.setUniformMatrix4fv("u_matrix", matrixBuffer, 1, false);
        particleProgram.setUniform1fv("u_Time", new float[] {currentTime}, 0, 1);

        /** Bind data **/
        particleSystem.bindData(particleProgram);

        particleSystem.draw();
    }
}
```

particle_shader.vs

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;
uniform float u_Time;

attribute vec3 a_Position;  
attribute vec3 a_Color;
attribute vec3 a_DirectionVector;
attribute float a_ParticleStartTime;

varying vec3 v_Color;
varying float v_ElapsedTime;

void main()                    
{                                         
    v_Color = a_Color;       
    v_ElapsedTime = u_Time - a_ParticleStartTime;    

    float gravityFactor = v_ElapsedTime * v_ElapsedTime / 8.0;

    vec3 currentPosition = a_Position + (a_DirectionVector * v_ElapsedTime);    
    currentPosition.y -= gravityFactor;    

    gl_Position = u_Matrix * vec4(currentPosition, 1.0);    
    gl_PointSize = 25.0;    
}
```

I

Comment: I have soon read through the same book as you and I have been thinking of what is the best approach to use particle effects in Libgdx. Doing it in this way makes you understand better what's going on, but it is a bit tedious and it will take quite some time to produce great results. Have you chekced the Particle Editor that ships with Libgdx? See [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Particle-editor). It looks awesome and it also an [API](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2d-particle-effects) that is currently not very well documented, it seems.

Comment: You are never calling glBindBuffer to bind your vertex data (would probably go in your `bindData` method. Are you just doing this as an exercise? You are skipping the use of many of Libgdx's classes that would make this way, way easier to do.